# Optimal Settings.php for Pressflow + Varnish + memcache

Tags: proxies, caching

I am using pressflow having varnish + boost + memcache and also using cloudflare caching, I have seen some variable forms of settings.php file on forums and I am confused whether mine is optimal for best usage of all these caching mechanism :

```
# Varnish reverse proxy on localhost
$conf['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;           
$conf['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = array('127.0.0.1'); 

# Memcached configuration
$conf['cache_inc'] = './sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache.inc';
$conf['memcache_servers'] = array(
         '127.0.0.1:11211' => 'default',
         );
### END Mercury settings written on 2011-11-01T07:12:49-04:00
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are doing something quite unique, using boost & varnish is usually overkill. If you have varnish setup exactly how you want it, I would just use varnish.

Here is an example settings.php. It is a multisite safe memcache configuration thanks to the memcache_key_prefix setting.

```
<?php
// Skip db query that checks for blocked IP's.
$conf['blocked_ips'] = array();

// Reverse proxy settings.
$conf['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;
$conf['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = array(
  '127.0.0.1',    // Localhost
);

// Use memcache for caches, locks, and sessions.
$conf['cache_inc'] = './sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache.inc';
$conf['lock_inc'] = './sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache-lock.inc';
$conf['session_inc'] = './sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache-session.inc';

// Memcache Settings.
// Set memcache server.
$conf['memcache_servers'] = array(
  '127.0.0.1:11211' => 'default',
);
// Set memcache bins.
$conf['memcache_bins'] = array(
  'cache' => 'default',
  'cache_form' => 'database',
);
// Set memcache prefix to be the location of the settings.php file.
$conf['memcache_key_prefix'] = basename(realpath(conf_path()));
// Try to use a persistent connection.
$conf['memcache_persistent'] = TRUE;
?>
```

Comment: Absolutely agree. Having both boost and varnish is pointless.

Comment: I like the blocked IPs trick.

Comment: If only I could upvote this configuration more than once! :)

Answer (score 0):

Earlier it was believed that Boost+Varnish do work good if configured correctly - [Is it redundant to use the "boost" module if varnish is used?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4127/is-it-redundant-to-use-the-boost-module-if-varnish-is-used?rq=1), has this changed by recent developments.