# Memcached tuning

Tags: 6, performance, caching

Does the memcache module works by default after instalation (by setting up the `$conf['cache_inc']` in the settings.php file ) or it needs some other tweaks or some custom code?

I have memcache up and running on a server and I can see the memcache debug messages. It looks like it is working fine but I can't see any improvements.

I'm using the drupal 6 version on the module.

Comment: "I can see the memcache debug messages". What are these messages saying? Memcache is quiet, it only writes to watchdog if there are errors.

Comment: the messages from the memcache module

Answer (score 1):

The memcache module works by default. You don't need to do anything else to get it working. There are some minor tweaks one can do though; here is what my settings.php file looks like:
[Optimal Settings.php for Pressflow + Varnish + memcache](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49038/optimal-settings-php-for-pressflow-varnish-memcache/49221#49221)