# Drupal 6 memcache configuration

Tags: 6, caching

I'm trying to use: [Memcache API and Integration | Drupal.org](https://drupal.org/project/memcache) w/ my Drupal6 and unable to determinate what am I doing wrong as when I hit `memcache.php` (MEMCACHE INFO) my `Cache Usage` shows me `100%` of `Free`.

here is my info:

`settings.php`

```
$conf['cache_inc'] = './sites/all/modules/contrib/memcache/memcache.inc';
$conf['memcache_servers'] = array(
        '192.168.52.153:11211' => 'default'
);
$conf['memcache_bins'] = array(
        'cache'         => 'default',
        'cache_filter'  => 'default',
        'cache_menu'    => 'default',
        'cache_page'    => 'default',
        'session'       => 'default',
        'users'         => 'default'
);
```

`drush`

```
 Performance and         Memcache (memcache)                                 Module  Enabled        6.x-1.10      
 Performance and         Memcache Admin (memcache_admin)                     Module  Enabled        6.x-1.10
```

`system`

```
# rpm -q php-pecl-memcache memcached
php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5-4.el6.x86_64
memcached-1.4.4-3.el6.x86_64
# service memcached status
memcached (pid  1482) is running...
#
```

`SELinux`

```
# getsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db
httpd_can_network_connect_db --> on
# getsebool httpd_can_network_memcache
httpd_can_network_memcache --> on
#
```

`iptables`

```
# iptables -L -n | grep 11211
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:11211 
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW udp dpt:11211 
#
```

`netstat`

```
# netstat -an | grep 11211
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11211               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::11211                    :::*                        LISTEN      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11211               0.0.0.0:*                               
udp        0      0 :::11211                    :::*                                    
#
```

Comment: if you have a drush, do `drush vget |grep cache` and post back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I had following line in `settings.php`

```
# grep cache_inc XXX.XXX.XXX/settings.php 
$conf['cache_inc'] = './sites/all/modules/contrib/memcache/memcache.inc';
#
```

something was "off":

```
# drush -r /var/www/html/current/ -l XXX.XXX.XXX vget cache_inc
No matching variable found.                                                                             [error]
#
```

I was able to pinpoint my issue inside of `setttings.php` file, that caused `cache_inc` not to loaded into array:

```
$conf = array(
        'mimedetect_magic' => '/usr/share/misc/magic.mgc',
);
```

So, I end up changing it to:

```
$conf['mimedetect_magic'] = '/usr/share/misc/magic.mgc';
```

And *NOW* my memcache start working right away! (I'm able to see HITs in `MEMCACHE INFO`)

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that your cache confiuration are working witout Memcache. Disable memcache modules and enable caching through  the UI or in settings.php

```
$conf['cache_lifetime'] = '1800';
$conf['cache'] = TRUE;
```

Then check the response headers for anonymous users and look for `x-drupal-cache`. If it is a `hit` then you have it working if it's a `miss` then you must investigate further. You can check the cache_page table in the database table to start with.

If DB caching is working, proceed and add the memache settings and enable the module. Memcache integration only divert db cache to memcache. Once you do this, truncate the cache_page table, then check it after visiting pages as anonymous user. You can also check Memcache statistics. If the table fills up then memcache is not working fine and we will need more info. You can use drush to check the settings. `drush vget |grep cache` and post back.

Lastly check cache settings at admin/performance/cache if it is set to external you need to change that to `normal` for Memcache to work.

Comment: I'm using `Varnish` and caching part _IS_ working, as far as `memcache` I'm not seeing even one single `HIT`.

Comment: How did you verify the caching part is working? do you see entries in the cache_page table? are you using the varnish module too? I suggest you disable varnish temporary (provided this is a local env) and debug.

Comment: Varnish is working fine, as I'm able to see `X-Cache: HIT`, so as I said before caching of pages is working fine! That's not an issue) yet `memcache` IS.

Comment: Varnish is completely different. It is another layer on top. If varnish is working or not does not tell you anything. Bypass varnish and check. Again, do you have the vanish module?

Comment: yes, I have varnish module.

Comment: then memcache is not gonna cache because varnish is taking care of it. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49038/optimal-settings-php-for-pressflow-varnish-memcache

Comment: here is `drush vget | grep cache` output: http://pastebin.com/QthFEW7f yet I'm still struggle to understand why you keep pointing to Drupal's cache settings when question is about `memcache`, which has nothing to do with Drupal's cache or Varnish.

Comment: Memcache works by diverting drupal cache into memcache. Putting all cache tables except for form into memory. Varnish only `used for page cache` and is external. Also, you have your cache setting `cache: 3` which is external. Memcache will not work with this setting. You need to change it to normal at `admin/settings/performance`

Comment: I'm confused, you're saying if my cache settings set to 3 (which is external) `memcache` won't work, yet it does, the reason it has to be set to 3 is for `Varnish` and as I said that several times already my Varnish and page caching itself _IS_ working and was never an issue at the first place, question was in re: to `memcache` not `Varnish`!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Basically you need to verify your db cache (normal mode) works before you add memcache. Memcache works with drupal. In other words every `cache_get` goes to memcache instead of database (with varnish you don't even get to `cache_get`. If memcache is not caching, I am inclined tobelieve that caching is not working at all. Lets move this to chat..